# executing SSIS package in MS SQL server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have deployed an SSIS project into the SSISDB. When I run the job, either manually (right click and execute) or through a job, it results in errors. I am getting the following errors below.

> Data Flow Task: Error: Flat file Source failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC020200E.

> Data Flow Task: Warning: The system cannot find the path specified. Data Flow Task: Error: Cannot open the datafile "C:\xxxxx\test.csv

Comment: Not enough information to diagnose your problem. Please post the full text of the errors. Additionally, what is the command you are using to execute the package (script the sql agent job). Where does the package live? What does the package _do_ Is there Excel involved? Are network shares involved? What account is running the failing package?

Comment: the package lives in MS SQL server and I am executing it by right-clicking and going to execute. The package is used to import the data stored in excel into a table in MS SQL server.  No network share has been involved yet. How do you determine the account running the failed package because that is what I am trying to do right now. ALso, that is the full-text of the error

Comment: As you say you click execute, so this package is deployed to the SSISDB? If so, in sql server management studio, find the Integration Services Catalog node and expand it. Right click on SSISDB and select Reports -> Standard Reports -> All Executions. Find the package you are running and all the associated messages generated. If you want to copy paste the errors, you will need to identify the operation/execution id in the upper left corner and then run a query like `SELECT * FROM SSISDB.catalog.operation_messages AS OM WHERE OM.operation_id = 12345;`

Comment: so I followed the guided instruction and I have a feeling it might be a permission issue. hence how do i determine what user is running the package in MS SQL server. in the meantime, the details of the error is Data Flow Task: Warning: The system cannot find the path specified. Data Flow Task: Error: Cannot open the datafile "C:\xxxxx\test.csv

Comment: You have a permission issue - `The system cannot find the path specified`

Comment: I'm going to edit your question to bring some of this good comment data into it but I strongly encourage you to read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the help center so you can understand how to get the most out of the asking portion of this site.

Comment: Thanks so far. But to be fair, the initial error summary that i saw being thrown by SSISDB was a bit vague, it was after I viewed the SSISDB.catalog.operation_messages that I was able to see further details associated with the error. Hence, I am trying to understand a) how to determine what user the SSISDB catalog uses to manually or schedule a job run? b) A solution to the permission issue.

Comment: Does `C:\xxxxx\test.csv` exist on the server where the package is deployed?  Manually running by right click execute from the integration services catalog in SSMS is run as the user who clicked execute.  As far as an agent job, depends if you are using a proxy account or not, in the job step if it says Run as 'SQL server Agent Service account", that is not a proxy, it is the user/account that is running the "SQL Server Agent" service on the server.

Comment: So let me understand correctly,  C:\xxxx\test.csv has to exist on the database server or is there another available option. I am asking due to the fact c:\xxxxx\test.csv exist on a file server instead. Thanks